# Android - How to copy the emulator to a friend for testing

Tags: android, emulation

I'd like to copy my whole emulator install to another computer with a desktop shortcut which will start it so that my friend can test my app. Has anyone done this?

Comment: I know copying an emulator is possible, I'm just not sure how.  Each AVD has a folder and a configuration file so you might try copying those.  However, I don't know of a way to start an emulator without the SDK, AVD manager, or ADB.  Why not just send your friend the .apk and install it on an emulator he has?

Comment: Added a quick tutorial, let me know if that works for you :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, **it's not true** that you need the complete SDK to run the emulator.
If you copy only these files from the Android SDK installation and from your AVD (i.e `~/.android/avd/my.avd`)

```
.
|-- cache.img
|-- config.ini
|-- emulator
|-- emulator-user.ini
|-- kernel-qemu
|-- ramdisk.img
|-- sdcard.img
|-- system.img
|-- userdata.img
|-- userdata-qemu.img
`-- WVGA800
    |-- arrow_down.png
    |-- arrow_left.png
    |-- arrow_right.png
    |-- arrow_up.png
    |-- background_land.png
    |-- background_port.png
    |-- button.png
    |-- controls.png
    |-- hardware.ini
    |-- keyboard.png
    |-- key.png
    |-- layout
    |-- select.png
    `-- spacebar.png
```

you will be able to start the emulator as

```
$ ./emulator -sysdir . -kernel kernel-qemu -ramdisk ramdisk.img -system system.img -skindir . -skin WVGA800 -datadir .
```

and any APK installed and configuration set will persist.
Your friend would only need to run this command line which you can put in a script.

Comment: I'll try this and write a quick little script to zip up this stuff and that would be easiest.

Comment: Exactly what I was imagining. Thanks!

Comment: I tried this on both Mac OS X and Windows 7.  It works great.  Thanks!

Comment: how to paste a file into avd? and vice versa.

Comment: This does not seem to work with Android SDK 22.3. `config.ini` got ignored and the emulator display stays black, the kernel log stucks at *Uncompressing Linux*. Are there other requirements that you have not mentioned? The files were put in `/tmp`.

Comment: FYI newer versions of Android appear to store the ramdisk.img, system.img, and userdata.img in the <sdk>/system-images folder (e.g. <sdk>/system-images/android-22/default/armeabi-v7a)

Comment: I got the error "emulator: ERROR: No AVD specified. Use '@foo' or '-avd foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'". Any one got it working?

Answer (score 2):

Prerequisites: **Your friend must have android SDK installed, with required API level, i.e. if you are developing in Android 1.6 your friend should have atleast 1.6 installed**

Well considering you situation I will **Recommend** you should give your friend the `<application-name>.apk` file that gets generated in your `project\bin` folder, since any method would either require a device or SDK installed on machine.

You can then ask your friend to install that `.apk` file with asking him\her to navigate to tools directory of sdk and executing `abd install "<.apk folder directory>.<apk-file-name>.apk"` when some avd is running, and can be created using `android create avd -n <name> -t <targetID>` from tools directory of sdk. [Complete tutorial on how to create avd is here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/avd.html).

But if you insist on doing a transfer of your entire AVD heres a quick untested tutorial.

Yes you can surely do that, I think. I haven't tried this on some other machine but hope this will help you.

Now

1. Go to your `.android\avd` directory, well I don't know about the other OS but in Windows 7 its at `C:\Users\<user-name>\.android\avd`
2. Copy the `<Android Virtual Device Name>.ini` file and `<Android Virtual Device Name>.avd` folder. Which you can paste it in may be your flash drive or do some online sharing I dont know you choose your way of transferring this data.
3. Open `<Android Virtual Device Name>.ini` with any text editor and change 
   `path=C:\Users\<your-user-name>\.android\avd\<Android Virtual Device Name>.avd` with 
   `path=C:\Users\<your-friends-name>\.android\avd\<Android Virtual Device Name>.avd`
   basically you are changing the path where the folder `.avd` lies.

Now to create a desktop short-cut

1. Create a blank text file with:

   ```
   cd <friends-sdk-directory>\tools
   <root drive of the friends sdk-directory> :
   emulator -avd <Android Virtual Device Name>
   ```

   and save it as `emulator_shortcut.bat`

Now when you start the bat file your emulator will start.

**Some notes:**

Make sure you edit `<friends-sdk-directory>`,`<Android Virtual Device Name>`,`<your-user-name>`,`<your-friends-name>`,`<.apk folder directory>`,`<apk-file-name>` with appropriate values.

Comment: I followed your recommendation and simply copied the sd file which I was able to specify when setting up the emulator on the other computer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good article how to copy already created AVD devices to new machine:

http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/08/24/how-to-export-and-import-android-virtual-device-avd-files/

A short description:

1. Find your avd folder on you machine, check your user directory. For me, with user name “blahti”, those locations are:

   Windows 7: \users\blahti.android

   Windows XP: C:\Documents and Settings\blahti.android\

   Linux/Mac: ~/.android
2. In avd folder do: Compress the device.avd folder and the device.ini file.
   (Replace “device” with the name of the device you want to copy. For example: Evo4g.avd, Evo4g.ini.)
3. Edit the ini file and make corrections, as needed:
   (a) user name could be different; (b) change slash in path to Windows or Unix slash.

Answer (score 0):

To run the emulator properly, you‘ll need three components

1. The emulator.exe in the `SDK_folder/tools/`
2. Android System images and emulator skins

   images are at 　`<SDK folder>/platforms/<specific platform>/images`
   　　　　skins are at  `<SDK folder>/platforms/<specific platform>/skins`

   Make sure the images and skins are under the same folder.

   If you use google apis as your target system, the images are at
   `<SDK folder>/add-ons/<specific google api version>/images`
3. User images which are also known as avds.
   You could create them with the AVD manager and the default location of the created AVDs depends on your OS. 
   For Win7, it is under `C:\Users\<user-name>\.android\avd` .

OK. Now you could move these three components to anywhere you want.

Say you've copied the emulator into `<My Emulator Dir>`,copied the system images and skins into `<System Image Dir>`, copied you specific avd into `<User Image Dir>`.

Now You could write a batch file to run the emulator. 
`<My Emulator Dir>\emulator.exe -sysdir <System Image Dir> -datadir <User Image Dir> -cache <User Image Dir>\cache.img`