# Running Android application on windows with one click

Tags: android, android-emulator

For my master project I am trying develop a android application and I have to prepare "How to run" guide is there a way to run emulator from saved snapshot with a batch file.

What I think about this issue is copying the Android-sdk folder to a DVD and run the SDK Manager.exe and starting the virtual device but the folder is almost 2.5 GB what is the minimum folders to do this.

Comment: Check this: http://www.redmondpie.com/android-emulator-for-windows/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575167/android-how-to-copy-the-emulator-to-a-friend-for-testing/4577449#4577449