# Android Avd running of flash drive

Tags: eclipse

So I created an AVD(eclipse) and moved all the files that were on my computer  to my flash drive,but every time I run the application on my computer or  another computer it says can not find a compatible AVD/no Avd exists. Is there any way that I can tell eclipse that i changed the loaction of the AVD and that it should read it off of my flash drive rather than my computer? Thanks much help would be appreciated

Comment: Details and directions in comments to this question:
[how to copy avd files][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575167/android-how-to-copy-the-emulator-to-a-friend-for-testing

Answer (score 0):

Add a new user environment variable (Windows):

Start Menu > Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings (on the left) > Environment Variables

Add a new user variable (at the top) that points your home user directory:

```
Variable name: ANDROID_SDK_HOME
Variable value: C:\Users\yourUsername
```

Comment: but how does  putting the variable value at C help make it run on the flash drive?