# Share Android emulator (with app installed) to someone to use without Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, command-line, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

[Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575167/android-how-to-copy-the-emulator-to-a-friend-for-testing but the answers on that question as deprecated and ages old]

I want to share my Android Emulator with my app installed to non-developers for testing purpose. I tried some ways mentioned in the answer above but those are outdated and does not work anymore. Is there a simple way I can share my Android emulator with a simple installation script such that user can execute the emulator just with the script without having android studio or doing complex steps?